# problem with celery state when launching several tasks together

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery task to upload videos to a server. It goes like this:

```
x=asynchronousupload.delay(idcf,i,info['recording_files'][ijk]['download_url']+"?access_token="+utils.generateToken(),uuids,tit,descr,who,info['recording_files'][ijk]['recording_start'],info['recording_files'][ijk]['recording_end'])
```

I call that for 10 videos in parallel doing so:

```
tasknum=0
if len(infou['meetings'])>0:
    uuids=[]
    mp4files = []
    taskcel = []
    for ij in range(len(infou['meetings'])):
            uuids.append(infou['meetings'][ij]['uuid'])

            conn.request("GET", "/apiurl/"+uuids[ij]+"/recordings", headers=headers)

            res = conn.getresponse()
            data = res.read()
-
            resrec=res.status

            if resrec == 200:

                info = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
                                                
                for ijk in range(numberrec):
                 
                    x=asynchronousuploadvimeo.delay(idcf,i,...)
                                                     
                    tasknum = tasknum + 1
                                                                                                                                 
                    taskcel.append(x.task_id)#and then save taskcel in db
```

I store the task numbers and then I'm able to check periodically the state of each task doing like so:

```
res = AsyncResult(taskid[ij])
res.ready()
res.state
```

The problem is that all tasks succeed (I see that the videos are uploaded where I want and the task functions execute themselves and return the right value) but it is only one task that returns SUCCESS in res.state. When this one task (I suppose the first one that finished) is finished I then stop everything and load the page but sometimes it is just too early and not everything is finished. I'd like to get the other tasks to show SUCCESS as well but even though I wait (and they executed everything they had to and returned the right value), it never ends up SUCCESS and remains PENDING.

What is happening?

Comment: can you add the code for calling 10 videos in parallel?

Comment: sure I do that now, hopefully, you see something

Comment: 1. can you try `taskcel.append(x.id)` (instead of `task_id`). 2. can you try `res = AsyncResult(taskid[ij], app=celery_app)` with your celery app as second argument?

Comment: Thanks. So I have tried (x.id and x.task_id return the same) and I still get res 740caed2-33f9-42b9-897e-03b4abce4be7 SUCCESS for the first task and then res  f56e0593-6896-46fc-8575-a4a8ec25163b PENDING for other tasks. Though the two tasks have succeeded as indicated by celery: Task conf.tasks.asynchronousuploadvimeo[740caed2-33f9-42b9-897e-03b4abce4be7] succeeded in 2.7939049259293824s: 'upload successful' and Task conf.tasks.asynchronousuploadvimeo[f56e0593-6896-46fc-8575-a4a8ec25163b] succeeded in 2.8091469039209187s: 'upload successful'. Any thoughts?

Comment: something is unclear in your code: you are storing the ids in `taskcel` and then you read from `taskid` array. Can you elaborate about the reading part? are you doing that manually? did you try to add the celery_app?

Comment: There is one bit I don't show where I store taskcel in visio[i].celery_task_id = taskcel and then visio[i].save() and then I just read what's in the db taskid = visio[i].celery_task_id. I have added the celery_app: app = Celery('conf', broker=settings.BROKER_URL), res = AsyncResult(taskid, app=app) but it didn't change anything...

Comment: not sure I understand, can you edit the question again with the code?

Comment: oh dear, I found what it was. somehow an extra space was in front of the taskid. Say it was '876', it was stored as ' 876' and so it didn't recognize it... Thanks anyway ItayB!!!